# How to query prolog database from prolog webpage?

Tags: http, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm using swipl. I'm trying to query the parts.pl database file below from a web page, but I'm not sure how to post the query and have it "query" the database and return those results.

I.e., what I'm expecting to be able to do is enter a query as I would on the swipl command line such as 'part(jeep, 100, A, B).' and have the same results returned to me on the page.

Can anyone give a bit of guidance on how to do this. Here's what I've got so far.

```
:- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_error)).
:- use_module(library(http/html_write)).
:- use_module(library(http/http_client)).

:- use_module(parts).

:- http_handler('/', my_query_form, []).

server(Port) :-
    http_server(http_dispatch, [port(Port)]).

my_query_form(Request) :-
    reply_html_page(
        my_style,
        [title('My Test')],
        [\page_content(Request)]).

page_content(_Request) -->
    html(
        [
        form([action='/landing', method='POST'], [
            p([], [
                label([for=model], 'Model '),
                input([name=model, type=textarea])
                    ]),
            p([], [
                label([for=major], 'Major '),
                input([name=major, type=textarea])
                    ]),
            p([], [
                label([for=minor], 'Minor '),
                input([name=part, type=textarea])
                    ]),
            p([], input([name=submit, type=submit, value='Search'], []))
        ])]).

:- http_handler('/landing', landing_pad, []).

landing_pad(Request) :-
    member(method(post), Request), !,
    http_read_data(Request, Data, []),
    format('Content-type: text/html~n~n', []),
    format('<p>', []),
    portray_clause(Data),
    format('</p<p>=======~n', []),
    portray_clause(Request),
    format('</p>').

:- multifile
    user:body//2.

user:body(my_style, Body) -->
    html(body([
        div(id(top), h3('Parts Query')),
        div(id(beta), p(i('(beta)'))),
        div(id(content), Body)
        ])).
```

This is my parts.pl file.

```
:- module(parts,[part/4]).
% part(model, major, minor, description).
part(jeep, 100, 1000, 'description of 100-1000').
part(jeep, 100, 1001, 'description of 100-1001').
part(jeep, 100, 1002, 'description of 100-1002').
part(jeep, 101, 1000, 'description of 101-1000').
part(jeep, 101, 1001, 'description of 101-1001').
part(jeep, 101, 1002, 'description of 101-1002').
part(ford, 101, 1000, 'description of 101-1000').
```

Update: (my latest which actually does query, but returns the entire database)

```
landing_pad(Request) :-
    member(method(post), Request), !,
    http_read_data(Request, Data, []),
    format('Content-type: text/html~n~n', []),    
    format('<p>', []),
    memberchk(model=Model, Data),
    findall(p(Model, Major, Minor, Description),
        part(Model, Major, Minor, Description), Descriptions),
    maplist(description, Descriptions),
    format('</p>').   

description(p(M,A,I,D)) :- format("~q ~q:~q - ~q</br>", [M,A,I,D]).
```

Comment: You've already managed to get impressively far on your own. I just don't see where you are calling `part/4` in the server code.... did you forget to put this in your question?

Comment: @Ender: You latest edit contains a mistake that makes the entire query fail. Also, even if you correct this, it does **not** return the entire database. Please check this more closely. It would definitely help if the elements in your example were chosen in such a way that you can more easily tell the entries apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *extremely* close.

All that remains is to actually **query** your database with the components that were specified. I give you part of this querying, and leave filling out the rest as an exercise:

```
landing_pad(Request) :-
    member(method(post), Request), !,
    http_read_data(Request, Data, []),
    format('Content-type: text/html~n~n', []),
    format('<p>', []),
    memberchk(model=Model, Data),
    findall(p(Major,Description), part(Model, Major, _, Description), Descriptions),
    maplist(description, Descriptions),
    format('</p>').
```

I have highlighted the new parts in **bold**.

The `findall/3` collects all matching parts. In this case, only the `Model` component is used from the form data. You can fill out the rest.

To show the descriptions, you can use for example:

```
description(p(M,D)) :- format("<p>~q: ~q</p>\n", [M,D]).
```

as the definition of `description/1`.

**Hint:** Note the use of the `~q` format specifier. It makes debugging a lot easier. You will see what I mean if you add the additional features as part of the query, because you need to distinguish between integers and atoms.

Comment: Thank you. At least I am able to query, even though currently it returns the entire database.

Comment: @Ender The Prolog top level has a very specific way of dealing with choice points (pressing `;` for further answers). You need to decide how to deal with this in the context of a reply on a web page. You can use [SWISH](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/) for inspiration.

Comment: @Ender: It does **not** return the entire database: When you insert `jeep`, it only returns the 6 entries where `mode=jeep` holds. When you insert `ford`, it only returns the one entry for `ford`.

Comment: @mat: apologies, all I had was jeeps in the database and what I meant was, when I query for a specific part using Major and Minor numbers, I get every part to a jeep in the database and not just that one specific part I was looking for.

Comment: Yes: As I said, I left filling out the rest as an exercise. The pattern is (almost) the same for the remaining fields. Just watch out for the difference between atoms and numbers...